# Store filepaths in a Database

Tags: php, mysql, filesystems

Im trying to get filepaths and filenames in a sql database.

i have a file called 'run.mp3' in '/music/single/' for this i would need to fill a table with:

```
id artist filename filepath

ai single run      /music/single/run.mp3
```

I've searched google for any explanation on this and since im rather new to php and mysql I really need assistance here.

What I have tried:

```
$files = scandir(../music/); 

foreach($files as $file) {
    $paths  = explode("/", $file);

    $artist = $paths[1];
    $song = $paths[2];

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO playlist (artist, song,filepath) VALUES ('$artist', '$song', '$file')";

mysqli_close($con);
```

EDIT output of `$print_r($files);`:

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => C418 - Alpha [3] => C418 - Beta ),
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => C418 - Alpha [3] => C418 - Beta ),
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => C418 - Alpha [3] => C418 - Beta ),
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => C418 - Alpha [3] => C418 - Beta )
```

Comment: Please post some code to show where you are stuck.

Comment: Updated with code. Doesnt throw errors but wont get table entries either

Comment: Please update your question (edit) with the result of print_r($files);

Comment: Thanks for the edit... Do you have any idea on this? I mean i can see the folders but not any files inside the folders. Nor do i have any idea how i should get this output in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a SQL or MySQL database? For MySQL you could use this. First open your connection. So fill in your database, username and password.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO your_table (artists, filename, filepath)
VALUES ('single', 'run', ' /music/single/run.mp3' )");


mysqli_close($con);
```

And take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp for more information.

Comment: I want to automate this so php scans folders and inserts the values itself.

Comment: And infact with this code i dont get any errors when i call the file but nor do i get any results in my table

Comment: Take a look what's in $file: echo $file; in your foreach.

Comment: nothing is displayed. the php file is in /www/includes. the dir to scan is in /www/music. is $files = scandir(../music/); corrent at this point?

Comment: No results. The php file is in '/www/includes/' and the dir I want to scan is '/www/music'.

Comment: Try: print_r($files) before your foreach() and looks whats inside $files.

Comment: there is still nothing displayed

Comment: That means $files is emtpy.Try scandir() with your absolute path, so scandir(/www/music/);

Comment: <?php
 $files = scandir('../music'); 
 print_r($files);
 ?> Does print an array

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) documentation could help you getting the path using PHP.

And once you have the path you could execute a `mysqli_query` command to make the insertion into the DB

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) you can find an useful example...