# MySQL - 2 while loops not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

In my table i have 'artist' and 'song' now I want to output the artist name followed by all songs from this artist in my database. Using one while loop like i did in my code below doesnt work.

```
<div class="panel-group space" id="accordion"> <!-- ACCORDION FOR FOLDER/TRACK SELECTION -->

  <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','raspberry','raspberryfm'); 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT artist FROM playlist ORDER BY artist");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $artistnbsp = str_replace(' ', '_', $row['artist']);
        $artist = $row['artist'];

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT song FROM playlist WHERE artist= $artist");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

        $song = $row['song'];
        echo '
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title align2 color2">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.$artistnbsp.'">
                  '.$artist.'
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right pb">Play All</button>
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
          <div id="collapse'.$artistnbsp.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body color2">'
            . $song .
            '</div>
          </div>
          </div>';
        }
        }
    mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `WHERE artist= $artist"` to `WHERE artist= '$artist'"` which could be a contributing factor here, where `$artist` needs to be quoted. I doubt that's an integer. Unlike `1` compared to `Stevie Ray Vaughan` ;-)

Comment: You are using $row in both loops which is over writing each other. Use $row2 instead.

Comment: this did work for me so thanks! but now i came to another problem, this image might explain a bit better: http://i.epvpimg.com/C1jbe.png what i wanted is one accordion for each artist filled with all its songs. now i get one for each song.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you try Robbert's answer below?

Comment: Yes it does work but the problem as seen on the image is still present.

Comment: Then, you need to place your comment(s) under his answer in order to get it to work the way you want it to, explaining your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done fixing it yourself, however your nested queries are unnecicary and can cause performance issues.

With a little array manipulation you can have one query instead of one per artist:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','raspberry','raspberryfm');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playlist");

$artists_songs=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  $artists_songs[$row['artist']][]=array(
      'song'=>$row['song'],
      'artist'=>$row['artist'],
      'artistnbsp'=>str_replace(' ', '_', $row2['artist'])
  );

}

foreach ($artists_songs as $artist) :?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title align2 color2">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $artist[0]['artistnbsp'];?>">
                <?php echo $artist[0]['artist'];?>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right pb">Play All</button>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<?php echo $artist[0]['artistnbsp'];?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body color2">
            <?php foreach($artist as $details):?>
                <p><?php echo $artist['song'];?></p>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. However I'll only load it once when i get in my car so i dont mind the performance. Could you possibly take a look at my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908095/store-filepaths-in-a-database

Comment: @Stantastic sure, i'll take a look. And even if this is just a personal project, good practice is worth learning

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `$row` from your first loop with your second while loop.  You should rename it to `$row2` or something

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  $artistnbsp = str_replace(' ', '_', $row['artist']);
  $artist = $row['artist'];

  $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT song FROM playlist WHERE artist= $artist");
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
```

Also, is `$artist` a numeric value? If not, the query above will fail unless you put quotes around `$artist`.  You should also consider using mysqli's parameter feature instead of putting the variable directly in the query.

Comment: this did work for me so thanks! but now i came to another problem, this image might explain a bit better: http://i.epvpimg.com/C1jbe.png what i wanted is one accordion for each artist filled with all its songs. now i get one for each song.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find and fix the problem myself. Thank you guys for helping me that fast!

```
            <div class="panel-group space" id="accordion"> <!-- ACCORDION FOR FOLDER/TRACK SELECTION -->

            <?php
                $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','raspberry','raspberryfm'); 
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT artist FROM playlist ORDER BY artist");

                    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                        $artistnbsp = str_replace(' ', '_', $row2['artist']);
                        $artist = $row2['artist'];


                        echo '
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title align2 color2">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.$artistnbsp.'">
                                            '.$artist.'
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right pb">Play All</button>
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            <div id="collapse'.$artistnbsp.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body color2">';

                                    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT song FROM playlist WHERE artist= '$artist'");
                                    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

                                        $song = $row3['song'];

                                            echo $song;
                                            echo "<br/>";

                                    }
                        echo '  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>';

                    }
                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
        </div>
```